# How to lock a transaction in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There is a case when request is sent multiple times to the server with same data. I want to insert that data in database using ORM of Django. In that data there is a field say 'field_imp' which can only be unique. Right now it gives me `integrity error` as both the request are trying to insert together. How do I avoid this condition?

**How to send multiple request together?**

Using `terminator` open multiple tabs, write the same `curl` request and send.

**Model in Django:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    field_imp = models.TextField(unique=True)
```

I am using `Django rest Framework` for the api generation and its `serializers` for data's validation.

Comment: No, normally *one* shell raise an error, and one will succeed: the first will succeed, and the second one will error since it already exists. The question here is: what do you *want* to happen in that case?

Comment: Yep, that is what is happening. I don't want the exception to be raised, instead show a correct message in the response.

Comment: But what is a *correct* message? :) If you want to "insert-or-fetch", you can use Django's `get_or_create`, but currently it is not clear what exactly the use case is here.

Comment: I just want it be be saved. Correct message is anything but `Respose 500` (I guess).

Comment: @ShashankSingh - then you should wrap `save()` in a try/except that catches the `IntegrityError` and handles it gracefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `get_or_create()` intead of `serializer.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

The first Method  is to lock table,but it is low efficiency;

The second Method is to add both two code points:

1. add exist check into the serializer.
2. add try...catch... for integrity error.